# JMeter How to stop the test when we reach specific error rate

Tags: performance, jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-3.2

I am running a performance test in JMeter. I wonder how to stop/abort the test exactly when it reaches 5% percentage.

Do we have an option like that?

Comment: Yes, you can do it by adding "Auto Stop Listener", as mentioned here: https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-autostop-listener-how-to-do-it-right

Comment: Any feedback on answer ? If ok it should be accepted and upvoted so that it's helpful to others. Thanks

Comment: @UBIKLOADPACK - Thanks alot. It worked as expected!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First install [plugins-manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/install/Install/) by download jar, putting it in lib/ext and restarting jmeter.

Then install [Auto-Stop](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/AutoStop/) Listener plugin:

[image: Auto-Stop install]

Add it to your plan and configure it this way:

[image: Error Rate configuration]

Note I have put 0 for other criterions to disable them.

Comment: Thanks for the +info. (notes)

Answer (score 0):

1. One of the options is using [AutoStop](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/AutoStop/) plugin. Example test plan: [AutoStopExample_ErrRate.jmx](https://jmeter-plugins.org/img/examples/AutoStopExample_ErrRate.jmx)
2. You can run your JMeter test using [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) tool as a wrapper, this way you will have real-time console and/or web reporting and possibility to benefit from extra features, one of them is [Pass/Fail Criteria Subsystem](http://gettaurus.org/docs/PassFail/) which is powerful and flexible way of applying custom failure conditions to your test. Moreover it will return non-zero exit code which makes your test scripting and [CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) friendly. Check out [Navigating your First Steps Using Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/navigating-your-first-steps-using-taurus) for more details if needed.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri - Taurus seems to be interesting. Gonna look into it and may be come up with some new threads of questions if required!